# Canonical 1-form local form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $Q$ be a smooth manifold, the tautological 1-form is a 1- form on $T^{*}Q$, so a smooth map $M \rightarrow T^{*} Q$.

The definition is the following: 
A point $x \in T^{*}Q$ has projection $q= \pi(x) \in Q$ represents a linear 1-form 
\begin{align*}
\alpha: T_qQ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
Now $\lambda_{can}$ is defined as 
\begin{align*}
(\lambda_{can})_x(v) = \alpha(\pi_{*} v)    \ \ \ \ \ \  (*)
\end{align*}
where $\pi : T^{*}Q \rightarrow Q $ is the bundle projection and $\pi_{*}: T(T^{*}Q) \rightarrow TQ$ its differential.

Then, in my lecture, it says

We choose local coordinates $(q_1,...,q_n) $ on open $U \subset Q$. Then locally on $Q$ any $1$-form can be written as 
\begin{align*}
\beta= \sum_{j=1}^n p_j d q_j \text{ for some local functions } p_j
\end{align*}
The coordinates $(p_1,...,p_n)$ on the fibers of $T^{*} \alpha$ are called dual to the $q_j$. \
Together, the $q_j$ and $p_j$ give local coordinates on $T^{*}Q$. In such coordinates 
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{can} = \sum_{j=1}^n p_j d q_j \in \Omega^{1}(\pi^{-1}(U))
\end{align*}

I do not really understand what is proven here. On $T^{*}Q$, we have some local coordinates $p_1,...,p_n,q_1,...,q_n$ and then it is clear that each one form is spanned by these coordinates, what is the claim here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You most certainly can *not* write any $1$-form that way. And of course they're referring to the structure of $\Bbb R^{2n}$ as $T^*\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Could you explain why? I see now, that the last part I wrote is of course wrong since $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is $2n$ dimensional. But looking at the other example, for $Q$ $n$-dim. I can find local coordinates $q_1,...,q_n$. Why can't I then write any 1-form in that way?

Comment: @user1 I think your confusion is that $\lambda_{can}$ is a $1$-form on $T^{*}Q$, not on $Q$. An arbitrary one-form on $T^{*}Q$ has a coordinate expression of the form $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j}(q,p)dq_{j}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(q,p)dp_{i},$$ where $f_{j},g_{i}$ are functions in the $q,p$-coordinates. So there really is something to prove here, namely that $f_{j}=p_{j}$ and $g_{i}=0$ in the case of $\lambda_{can}$.

Comment: @User1: A $1$-form on $Q$ (not on $T^*Q$) can be written locally as $\sum f_i(q)dq_i$, but these coefficient functions are arbitrary and are certainly not independent coordinates $p_i$, as they are functions of $q$. Even if you take them to be functions of $p$, they needn't be giving you $n$ independent functions of $p$, locally. What if they're all constants?